# How to break a long line with multiple bracket pairs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, line-breaks, pep8

How to break a long line with multiple bracket pairs to follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)’s 79-character limit?

```py
config["network"]["connection"]["client_properties"]["service"] = config["network"]["connection"]["client_properties"]["service"].format(service=service)
```

Comment: @BearBrown While questions asking for code improvements may get good answers there, this question is asking for help with achieving a clear, objective change; it's not off-topic.

Comment: @TylerH i think this is good question for `codereview`

Comment: @BearBrown though it my be on-topic for codereview that [does not make it off-topic for SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312867/8150685). Code review can't handle a mass influx of questions so you should ask if it is truly a code review question or a question that is on-topic for SO (and if it is on-topic then just leave it alone)_. I would argue this is just as much on-topic as a question asking how to access an element in a dictionary (though that is a duplicate).

Comment: @BearBrown going along with Error - Syntactical Remorses' comment: this post would not have enough context for CR; Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353), [_Migration of code questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353) and [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: PEP-8's limit is for standard-library code only. It has no problem with teams, by agreement, using a longer length for their own code.

Comment: This is not opinion-based, even if there are more than one solution.

Comment: what happens if one of the path elements does not exist?

Comment: Voting to reopen: this is not opinion-based, the question was not "how should I best format this?" but "how does PEP 8 say I should format this?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [black](https://black.now.sh/?version=stable&state=_Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARYAAAB0L-Wj4ADnAHZdAD2IimZxl1N_WlXpD4Gl3TUdHZMrFCSpGAJ1b1MD7E78BVls8bMmy473ddDqAemq0pko5-2yNtfnQbEo9IgRPnC1whcxvRSYZt2vYnh07Lfn1Y9RzIsBOcru3YfnxjK8W9miCPHzhG4pf9YSrsr4P-zZr2A3EwAAAAClKPX3UH9h2QABkgHoAQAAxUmSvLHEZ_sCAAAAAARZWg==), the opinionated, reproducible code formatter:

```
config["network"]["connection"]["client_properties"][
    "service"
] = config["network"]["connection"]["client_properties"][
    "service"
].format(
    service=service
)
```

Comment: It might be opinionated, but black won't read the code after you. People would. And this looks much more confusing than other solutions.

Comment: hehe, this is a vast topic @YevhenKuzmovych; I agree, maybe it is not for everyone, but it is good to know it exists, and it works very well for some. There is a pycon video that presents black; I cannot access right now, but maybe you could find it and watch it if you have an interest.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych having a standard is more important than whether that standard is the best outcome for every situation. Lots of projects use black, so even though this isn't necessarily the most readable it's not going to be too much trouble for someone used to it.

Comment: @JaredSmith The first chapter (after introduction) of PEP 8: [A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds). "Readability counts"!

Comment: Exactly @JaredSmith, thank you - I would add that preserving consistency in spite of many people amending the same piece of code is not foolish, it is great. YMMV.

Comment: It also saves a lot of everybody's time figuring out how to break down long lines like the OP's sample, and cuts short on endless arguing about the best way to format the code. So much winning!

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I find this readable (not very, but readable). However I would have written the `format(service=service)` part on a single line. Breaking the line here is useless and harms readability.

Comment: Thanks @ReblochonMasque for mentioning `black`.

Comment: You are welcome; this particular snippet is not black's finest hour indeed. Overall, it has a few advantages, some of which I listed above, and I believe it is worth giving it a shot, to see if you like it or not.

Comment: black is just one guys preferences codified into a tool - and a lot of lemmings saying "must have a standard no matter how horrid it is".

Comment: The 79 character limit combined with code formatters makes for truly ugly code, this is only a fashion in Python.

Answer (score 16):

Considering the fact that Python works with references you can do the following:

```
properties = config["network"]["connection"]["client_properties"]
properties["service"] = properties["service"].format(service=service)
```

Comment: The most readable answer. The only drawback is that it introduces a temporary name.

Answer (score 9):

Use a `\`:

```
config["network"]["connection"]["client_properties"]["service"] = \
    config["network"]["connection"]["client_properties"]["service"].format(
        service=service
    )
```

Comment: The most readable answer that does not resort to a temporary name.

Answer (score 2):

You also could use a variable for better reading:

```
client_service = config["network"]["connection"]["client_properties"]["service"]
client_service = client_service.format(service=service)

# If you are using the value later in your code keeping it in an variable may
# increase readability
...
# else you can put it back
config["network"]["connection"]["client_properties"]["service"] = client_service
```

Comment: Your first and last lines are 81 characters long.

Comment: Ay, you are right. Than my suggestion probably wont work here since you cant really decrease that size without cutting the variable name even shorter which is not advisable here.

Comment: This does not modify the value of `config["network"]["connection"]["client_properties"]["service"]`.

Comment: @Maggyero it *should*. That last line should reassign the value in the nested dict.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets permit implicit line continuation. For example,

```
config["network"
]["connection"
]["client_properties"
]["service"] = config["network"]["connection"]["client_properties"]["service"].format(
service=service)
```

That said, I don't think there's any consensus as to which line each bracket should go on. (Personally, I've never found *any* choice that looks particularly "right".)

A better solution would probably be to introduce a temporary variable.

```
d = config["network"]["connection"]["client_properties"]
d["service"] = d["service"].format(service=service)
```